# Where in Brahmanda Purana it is mentioned about Parthasarathy Temple?

Tags: temple, identification-request, brahmanda-purana

The official website of Parthasarathy temple's history section states that according to Brahmanda Purana, **king sumathi requested Venkatesha to grant him darshanam of Geethacharya.**

I would like to know in which Bhaga/adhyaya/sloka of the Brahmanda Purana it is said so.